# Node.js 'Object is not a function' for payload() on second run

Tags: node.js, bluebird

This code is to where a user enters their username/password they get a token back. I have it to where if they enter the wrong info and get a 401, they get the prompt again to try again with `.catch(function(err) { callApiToken(); })`. However, on the second pass I will get `Unhandled rejection TypeError: object is not a function` for `payload(user, pass)` function. Why is this?

```
function payload(user, pass) {
    return payload = {
            "thePassword": {
                "username": user,
                "password": pass
           } 
      }
}

function postAsync(url, payload) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        rest.postJson(url, payload)
        .on('fail', function(data, response) {
            httpFail(data, response, reject);
            reject(response.statusCode);
         })
        .on('error', function(err, response) {
            conError(err, response);
            reject(err);
         })
        .on('success', function(data, response) {
            writeToFile(data, response);
            resolve();
        });
    });
}



function getPassword(user) {
    return readAsync({prompt: "Password: ", silent: true, replace: "*" })
        .then(function(pass) {
                //PAYLOAD() IS WHERE THE ERROR IS AT SECOND TIME
                //BEING CALLED
            return postAsync(URL, payload(user[0], pass[0]));
        });
}
```

How it is called:

```
callApiToken()
    .then(function() { refreshToken(); })
    .catch(function(err) {
        callApiToken();
    });
```

Comment: and, what does callApiToken do?

Comment: callApiToken is the main function which calls getUsername() -> getPassword() -> postAsync(). So.... `callApiToken = require('script).getUsername;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is the payload function itself, particularly this part:

```
return payload = {
    "thePassword": {
         "username": user,
         "password": pass
    } 
}
```

What that does, is it sets payload to "thePassword" object, so that after the first call, is no longer a function but an object instead.

Do this instead:

```
function payload(user, pass) {
    return { 
             "thePassword": {
                "username": user,
                "password": pass
           } 
      }
}
```